# How do I solve the error, "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code I'm using, its suppose to get a line from the text file and separate it and get the key at the end and use that to get all the lines in order from least to greatest and make a paragraph, I cant find out how to fix the error IndexError: list index out of range "if book_list[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7WiA.png) in book_dict:", can someone help me?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWV07.png)

[The book_data.txt file looks like this and I need to sort it, as stated above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7WiA.png)

Comment: I think sys.argv[0] is usually the name of the python file. I think what you want is sys.argv[1].

Comment: You can copy paste the code directly into the question box and format it properly using the formatting tools of the text box. You don't have to paste the link to an image of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It means `book_list` does not have have 3 elements. So `book_list[2]` is raising the error that you are trying to access an element that does not exist.
Index in python start from 0, so a 2 element list will have final element at `book_list[1]`.

If you are accessing the last element, you can also do `book_list[-1]`. This always gives the last element.

Answer (score 0):

An IndexError means that your code is trying to access an index that is invalid.

Let me explain it to you this way:
You have a list of 5 elements: [‘a’,’b’,’c’,’d’,’e’]
Now the max length is 5, so the indexes you can use to access the array are 0,1,2,3,4.

But if you try to access `my_list[8]` this would return you an error stating an index error that points to the invalid index to get an item from a list that doesn’t exist.

Trying to understand your case, you can do the following, you need to make sure that the variable `book_list` has atleast 2 elements within it to access the second element.

In simple words, you can’t take out 2 apples from a box that contains only 1 or no apples.

Answer (score 0):

@Trishant Pahwa Explain it very well, this error means that you are trying to get an item that doesn't exist. let say

```
book_list = ['book_01', 'book_02', 'book_03']
```

In this case, `book_list` is a list of length 3 (three items) but since the list uses an index you will have 0, 1, and 2 indexes.

if you want to get `book_01` you will use `book_list[0]` because the item is in the index 0.
Now if you try to do `book_list[3]` you will get the error `IndexError` because there is nothing in index 3.

we will need to know what is in book_data.txt to know what are you getting in the line 9 `book_list = book_line.strip().split("|")`

---

**ADDED**

Here I made an example, it not might solve all your questions but will give you an idea

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    book_dict = {}

    with open('books.txt','r') as file:
        book_file = file.readlines()
        print(book_file)

        book_quotes = {}

        for book_line in book_file:
            book_list = book_line.strip().split('|')
            # make keys int so can be sort later
            keys = int(book_list[1])
            print(f'this {book_list[0]} and {keys}')
            book_quotes[keys] = book_list[0]
        print(book_quotes)

        order = OrderedDict(sorted(book_quotes.items()))
        print(order)

main()
```

Please note:

1. It is not the best implementation but it is simple.
2. I use `with` and `open` to open the file. (I recreated the book.txt file).
3. I'm using `OrderDict` from the module `Collections`.

Comment: I added what the book_data.txt looks like if you wanna take a look and understand what I'm doing wrong better